# Handling login event from Facebook Like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to do some action when a user is logged in with Facebook.

It is easy when user is already logged in while loading page.

On my page there is a Facebook Like button, and when a user is not logged in, he or she can log in to Facebook by clicking the Like button.

In such a case events `auth.login` and `auth.statusChange` are not being thrown.

Is there a method to determine if a user is being logged in after clicking a Like button?